# How to make the same distance between <span> tags with only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following page structure:

```
<span>content01</span>
<span>content02</span>
<span>content03</span>
<br/>
<span>content04</span>
<span>content05</span>
<span>content06</span>
<br/>
<span>content07</span>
<span>content08</span>
<span>content09</span>
<br/>
...
```

As a result my data looks like a table with three columns.
The content of each `span` tag is some one word. But this looks crooked because all the words are different and have different lengths. And I want to have the same distance between the columns in each row. My problem could be easily solved by using a `table` tag or wrapping each `span` in a single `div`. But I want to achieve the desired result only by using CSS. Is this possible? For example I tried to use the following:

```
span {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 40px;  
}
```

Or the following:

```
span {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 40px;  
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `width` & `height` style do not apply for inline element

Comment: Is it tabular data? If so, use a `table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **display** property on the span tag should be `**inline-block**`, because **span tags** are `inline` by default, and we need it to act as a **block** as well.

So simply change `inline` into `inline-block`, like so:

```
span {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 40px;
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mAX59/

Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/span

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `display: inline-block` property and then it will works.

**Note:** The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document and you cannot set `width` or `height` on inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

try to insert in the css:

```
 .cell{
display:inline-block; width: 60px;
    }
```

and then in the HTML

```
<span class="cell"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: `width` doesn't work on inline elements. Give your `span`s
 a style of `display:inline-block` in addition to the styles you have now.

But there is more to your question. Your reasoning for not wanting to use a table is vague, and makes it sound like you belong to the "never use tables, as tables are evil" crowd.
Don't fall into that trap. Tables are good. Tables are useful! Sure, yes, they can be abused, but you can abuse other elements too. The way you're doing is now is abuse of `<br>` elements!

Comment: Tables are useful *for tabular data*.

Comment: Yes, or, as the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1) formulates it, "The HTML table model allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells." That document doesn't contain the word "tabular", by the way.

Comment: General consensus in the web community seems to be that tables are for tabular data *only*, and indeed the HTML5 working draft [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-table-element.html#the-table-element)  very clearly that “tables should not be used as layout aids.”